# Symfony2, OneToOne relation always duplicate error

Tags: php, symfony

I have a OneToOne relation between User.php and Timesheet.php.

Here you can see my code :

```
                $toDelete = 
$this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('VitamedicsProjectBundle:Timesheet')
->findOneBy(array('name' => 'timesheet', 'user' => $this->getUser()));
                if($toDelete){
                    $this->_em()->remove($toDelete);
                    $this->_em()->flush();
                }

                $timesheet->setUser($this->getUser());
                $timesheet->setName('timesheet');
                $this->_em()->persist($timesheet);
                $this->_em()->flush();
```

So, if a user is already link to a timesheet, i need to remove the timesheet before add another.

When i try this code, if i have already a timesheet, the line in database is removed when i test, but i always have the error `Duplicate entry....`

I thought if i remove and flush before persist and flush another it would have worked..

Comment: Does it say what was the duplicated value? Which `DBMS` do you use?

Comment: I don't understand why you actually remove an entity, and then instantly persist it back. Seems senseless.

Answer (score 0):

Well, probably you have `User` entity as the owning side. When you flush, you still have timesheet object set in your user object, so manager doesn't remove it (or remove and create a new one instantly).

So, the thing you need to do is unlink timesheet from the user object:

```
if($toDelete){
    $this->getUser()->setTimesheet(null);
    $this->_em()->remove($toDelete);
    $this->_em()->flush();
}
```